# Are there any security issues in sending json data, b/w .NET app and React app running in Cef browser, through Cef events?

Tags: .net, reactjs, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have a .NET (WinForms) app. A React app can be launched from inside the WinForms app (this React app is loaded in Cef browser). I am able to send data between the 2 apps (WinForms and React inside Cef) using [ExecuteJavaScriptAsync method](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IFrame_ExecuteJavaScriptAsync.htm). I noticed that I am able to send json data of any size i.e., there are no size limitations. Is sending such a big json data via Cef events safe? Can the confidential json data be hacked by anyone?

Comment: With local access anything can be hacked by anyone.Technically CEF sends data via chromium's IPC mechanism. So you need to decide if this channel secure enough for you, but i should note what if running host are compromised - nothing can help to prevent data leaks in any system.

Comment: @Dmitry Azaraev By 'running host', do you mean the .NET WinForms app?

Comment: How does size of JSON data relate to security exactly?

Comment: @MAK by running host I'm mean PC where program running. It is sometimes not bad idea to protect sensitive data which passes even over local pipes or so, but on another side, if PC are infected/compromised, together with administrative privileges - then for malicious software will be many other (and potentially easier) ways to capture data of intereset (key logging, memory dumps) from alternative sources. I mean what encryption might be absolutely useless for such cases, while under normal case there is impossible to intercept pipe.

Comment: @MAK because, time when normal case turns to non-normal case - we don't know, and we can't predict clearly even possibility of threats (because there is impossible to know everything), more over things get changed over time without notice => in this sense there is always have sense somehow protect user and data. But, If you will send encrypted data... it might be better, but at same time if only what you do is decrypt it and store as plain text => then there is no any sense to do that. There is also was good example what blind use of SecureString makes system only weaker than it was without.

Comment: @amaitland Yes, the size is not related to security. However, I send a lot of confidential data in that big JSON.

Comment: Thank you @DmitryAzaraev. http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefSettingsBase_CachePath.htm. If I don't specify cache path explicitly, then Cef browser is launched in 'incognito mode' and data are not persisted on disk (only in-memory). So, is this a solution to prevent attack on data at rest? Also, as you said, the data in transit is safe as long as the PC's security is not compromised.

Comment: What is data at rest exactly? Do you have a list of specific security concerns? Are you concerned with authorised users copying data?

Comment: @amaitland I don't want the data transferred through Cef browser to be stored locally in the PC

Comment: If you don't specify a CachePath then an in memory cache is used, no data is persisted to disk. This also means no cookies will be saved. If your data is exceptionally sensitive I'd probably look at disabling drag and drop, disable command line args so you cannot enable remote debugging, disable copy/paste. Lots of things to consider.